# Misunderstanding java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I have this activity:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ImagenesAlumnoActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    /**
     * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
     * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
     * {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which will keep every
     * loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory intensive, it
     * may be best to switch to a
     * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
     */
    private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

    /**
     * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
     */
    private ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_imagenes_alumno);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections of the activity.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

    }

    public int getScreenWidth() {

        DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
        int width=dm.widthPixels;

        return width;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_imagenes_alumno, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.ajustes:
                return true;
            case R.id.modo_edicion:
                Intent intent = new Intent(ImagenesAlumnoActivity.this, ModoAlumnoActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("alumno", "Alumno");
                startActivity(intent);
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";
        private GridViewImageAdapter adapter1;
        private GridViewImageAdapter adapter2;
        public GridView gridView;
        public GridView gridSiNo;
        private int anchoColumna;
        private List<Imagen> imagenes = new ArrayList<Imagen>();
        private List<Imagen> siNo = new ArrayList<Imagen>();
        MediaPlayer player;

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        /**
         * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
         * number.
         */
        public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
            PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }




        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_imagenes_alumno, container, false);
            ArrayList<Imagen> imagenesParaMostrar = new ArrayList<Imagen>();
            gridView = (GridView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.grid_view);
            gridSiNo = (GridView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.gridSiNo);
            double mult = 0.8;
            double mult2 = 0.2;
            inicializarGrilla(Constantes.CANTIDAD_COLUMNAS, Constantes.PADDING_GRILLA, gridView, mult);
            inicializarGrilla((Constantes.CANTIDAD_COLUMNAS - 2), Constantes.PADDING_GRILLA, gridSiNo, mult2);
            int position = this.getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER);
            imagenesParaMostrar.clear();
            siNo.clear();
            for (Imagen imagen : Datos.imagenes){
                if ((imagen.getCategoria()) == position ) {
                    imagenesParaMostrar.add(imagen);
                }
            }
            siNo.add(new Imagen("Si", "si"));
            siNo.add(new Imagen("No", "no"));
            adapter1 = new GridViewImageAdapter(this.getActivity(),imagenesParaMostrar,anchoColumna);
            gridView.setAdapter(adapter1);
            adapter2 = new GridViewImageAdapter(this.getActivity(), siNo, anchoColumna);
            gridSiNo.setAdapter(adapter2);
            return rootView;
        }

        private void inicializarGrilla(int cantidadColumnas, int paddingGrilla, GridView gv, double mult) {
            anchoColumna = (int) (((this.getScreenWidth()* mult) - ((cantidadColumnas + 1) * paddingGrilla)) /cantidadColumnas);
            gv.setNumColumns(cantidadColumnas);
            gv.setColumnWidth(anchoColumna);
            gv.setStretchMode(GridView.STRETCH_COLUMN_WIDTH);
            gv.setPadding(paddingGrilla, paddingGrilla, paddingGrilla, paddingGrilla);
            gv.setHorizontalSpacing(paddingGrilla);
            gv.setVerticalSpacing(paddingGrilla);
            gv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {

                    Imagen imagen = (Imagen) gridView.getAdapter().getItem(position);
                    player = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), imagen.getSonido());
                    player.start();
                }
            });


        }

        public int getScreenWidth() {

            DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
            getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
            int height = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
            int width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
            return width;
        }

    }


    /**
     * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
     * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
     */
    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
            // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
            return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 4 total pages.
            return 5;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return "PISTA";
                case 1:
                    return "ESTABLO";
                case 2:
                    return "EMOCIONES";
                case 3:
                    return "NECESIDADES";
                case 4:
                    return b.getString("alumno");
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    public void loadBitmap(int resId, ImageView imageView) {
        BitmapWorkerTask task = new BitmapWorkerTask(imageView, getResources());
        task.execute(resId);
    }


}
```

I have an action bar, and in this one I have two options. When I select Modo Edicion I want to go to another activity.

Here's the code from the other activity:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Lupi on 27/12/2015.
 */
public class ModoAlumnoActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

    /**
     * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
     */
    private ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_modo_edicion);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar1);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections of the activity.
       mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container1);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs1);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_modo_edicion, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.ajustes:
                return true;
            case R.id.modo_edicion:
                Intent intent = new Intent(ModoAlumnoActivity.this, ImagenesAlumnoActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }


    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";
        private GridViewImageAdapter adapter1;
        private GridViewImageAdapter adapter2;
        public GridView gridView;
        public GridView gridSiNo;
        private int anchoColumna;
        private List<Imagen> imagenes = new ArrayList<Imagen>();
        private List<Imagen> siNo = new ArrayList<Imagen>();
        MediaPlayer player;

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        /**
         * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
         * number.
         */
        public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
            PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }




        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_imagenes_alumno, container, false);
            ArrayList<Imagen> imagenesParaMostrar = new ArrayList<Imagen>();
            gridView = (GridView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.grid_view);
            gridSiNo = (GridView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.gridSiNo);
            double mult = 0.8;
            double mult2 = 0.2;
            inicializarGrilla(Constantes.CANTIDAD_COLUMNAS, Constantes.PADDING_GRILLA, gridView, mult);
            inicializarGrilla((Constantes.CANTIDAD_COLUMNAS - 2), Constantes.PADDING_GRILLA, gridSiNo, mult2);
            int position = this.getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER);
            imagenesParaMostrar.clear();
            siNo.clear();
            for (Imagen imagen : Datos.imagenes){    /* Hay que traer las imagenes del nene/a */
                if ((imagen.getCategoria()) == position ) {
                    imagenesParaMostrar.add(imagen);
                }
            }
            siNo.add(new Imagen("Si", "si"));
            siNo.add(new Imagen("No", "no"));
            adapter1 = new GridViewImageAdapter(this.getActivity(),imagenesParaMostrar,anchoColumna);
            gridView.setAdapter(adapter1);
            adapter2 = new GridViewImageAdapter(this.getActivity(), siNo, anchoColumna);
            gridSiNo.setAdapter(adapter2);
            return rootView;
        }

        private void inicializarGrilla(int cantidadColumnas, int paddingGrilla, GridView gv, double mult) {
            anchoColumna = (int) (((this.getScreenWidth()* mult) - ((cantidadColumnas + 1) * paddingGrilla)) /cantidadColumnas);
            gv.setNumColumns(cantidadColumnas);
            gv.setColumnWidth(anchoColumna);
            gv.setStretchMode(GridView.STRETCH_COLUMN_WIDTH);
            gv.setPadding(paddingGrilla, paddingGrilla, paddingGrilla, paddingGrilla);
            gv.setHorizontalSpacing(paddingGrilla);
            gv.setVerticalSpacing(paddingGrilla);
            gv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {

                    Imagen imagen = (Imagen) gridView.getAdapter().getItem(position);
                    player = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), imagen.getSonido());
                    player.start();
                }
            });


        }

        public int getScreenWidth() {

            DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
            getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
            int height = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
            int width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
            return width;
        }

    }


    /**
     * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
     * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
     */
    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

        Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
            // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
            return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 4 total pages.
            return 1;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return b.getString("alumno");
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    public void loadBitmap(int resId, ImageView imageView) {
        BitmapWorkerTask task = new BitmapWorkerTask(imageView, getResources());
        task.execute(resId);
    }
}
```

When I click on Modo Edicion the app close itself, and returns this error:

> 12-28 13:00:45.942 1337-1360/? W/Binder: 
>   Caught a RuntimeException from the binder stub implementation. Java.lang.NullPointerException
>  at android.inputmethodservice.IInputMethodWrapper.setSessionEnabled(IInputMethodWrapper.java:280)
>   at com.android.internal.view.IInputMethod$Stub.onTransact(IInputMethod.java:129)
>   at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:404)
>  
>   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method) 12-28 13:00:45.942
>   1253-1474/? W/InputMethodManagerService:
>   Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 1791 uid 10056

---

Could anyone tell me how to fix it?. Thanks.

Comment: All that code you posted is noise. Run the code in a debugger and you'll see what's null in minutes.

Comment: Possible dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it